# Is it possible to not generate a new primary key value if already set?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation in which I find the next sequence value (using nextval), set it to a database column and I want to reuse that value as the object's primary key. The problem is that although I triggger save with the correct values, Spring JPA generates another primary key and does not use the one I gave it.

For example, I have an entity:

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_MY_ENTITY")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SEQ_MY_ENTITY", allocationSize = 1, name = "SEQ_MY_ENTITY")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "field1")
    private String field1;
```

In some business flow, I need to set field1 = id. I do this by:

1. get next val from dual.
2. set value to field1
3. set value to id

Problem is that what is saved for id = field1 + 1. How can I have the two values in sync without calling save with empty field1 and then another save after I've updated field1?

Comment: This is a really bad idea for so many reasons.     The database should be generating the primary keys.   You doing it there could be an insert that happens after you have the sequence value but before you start your insert it you would be using an existing key which will  lead to either uniqueness constraint exceptions or worse over writing an existing record.      Additionally with some JPA libs having the PK field populated will cause it to assume you are doing an update and might over write some other record.   If both columns are going to be the same value then why have two columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Id on two columns : id and field1 or use composite key using @Embeddable